# Concurrent download/processing in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'm looking for the fastest and most reliable approach to downloading 1000 remote webpages (using HttpWebRequest) concurrently using C#, writing them to individual local files and running some processing code once all files have been downloaded, while making the best use of parallelism and non-blocking concurrency available.

The server is a quad core (vCPU) VPS running Windows 2008 and .NET 4.0 (can't use the newer async/await stuff).

What do you suggest?

**Update:** Options proposed so far are: Reactive Extensions (Rx), Async CTP, TPL.

Looks like Async CTP would be the ideal way to do it, followed by Rx and TPL. What say guys?

Comment: Do all of those pages come from a single website or from 1000 different sites?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think WebClient supports multi-threading natively.

Comment: @svick All pages come from different sites.

Comment: @Nick the WebClient has async methods that won't take an extra ThreadPool thread.

Comment: @Christoph / Ramhound I suppose you guys are referring to the WebClient async methods, as shown in James Cuthbert's example below http://stackoverflow.com/a/11611613/1157545

Comment: Rx is more powerful than Async, but Async is easier to learn. IMO.

Answer (score 5):

No matter which async approach you end up using, don't forget that you need to increase the max connections allowed as the default is ***2 per domain***. So if you make a lot of calls against a single domain, you will be rate limited to that.

You can fix this in a standalone (non-ASP.NET) app using basic config:

```
<system.net>
   <connectionManagement>
       <add address="*" maxconnections="200" />
   </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

However, if you're in ASP.NET this will not work as expected since the default `<processModel autoConfig="true" ...>` attribute will cause it to auto configure to 12 per core which, while better than 2 total, still might not suit your needs. So then you will have to use the code-based approach in something like your Application_Start:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
```

NOTE: this code based approach also works equally well for non-ASP.NET apps, so you could use it as a "universal" solution if you want to avoid .config.

Answer (score 4):

I would use Rx for that task.

```
string[] webpages = { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.spiegel.de"};

webpages
    .Select(w => FetchWebPage(w))
    .ForkJoin()
    .Subscribe(x => /*This runs when all webpages have been fetched*/  Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Or if you like to control the concurrency to process max 4 requests concurrently as svick suggested you could change it to this:

```
Observable.ForkJoin(
    webpages
        .Select(w => FetchWebPage(w))
        .Merge(4))
        .Subscribe(x => /*This runs when all webpages have been fetched*/  Console.WriteLine(x));
```

You also neeed a helper method to transform from the regular async way to the Rx way

```
public static IObservable<string> FetchWebPage(string address)
{
    var client = new WebClient();

    return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
    {
        DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Cancelled)
                observer.OnCompleted();
            else if(args.Error != null)
                observer.OnError(args.Error);
            else
            {
                observer.OnNext(args.Result);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        };

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += handler;

        try
        {
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }

        return () => client.DownloadStringCompleted -= handler;
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you modify this to limit the degree of parallelism? Because I don't think starting 1000 downloads at the same time is a good idea.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Rx uses TPL internally. It also looks like TPL provides more direct control over async operations than Rx.

Comment: @Nick: Rx uses its own intrinsics (schedulers, etc). I don't believe it's built on TPL.

Comment: `Observable.ForkJoin()` seems to be only in Rx for Windows Phone, but not in normal Rx. Am I right? How would you write this using normal Rx then?

Comment: Nope, it's in the latest beta. However, one can trivially write a ForkJoin alternative if it's missing. I'm on mobile now but here is how to write it in RxJS. It's pretty much the same as in C# https://github.com/cburgdorf/rxjs-contribute#L82

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 SP1 can use the Async CTP to do `async`/`await` on .NET 4.0.
VS2012 RC can use the Async Targeting Pack to do `async`/`await` on .NET 4.0.

But if you really don't want to use `async`/`await`, you can still use tasks and continuations (the Task Parallel Library is part of .NET 4.0).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar need, but for me the URL count is over 7,000 (used to take about 25 - 28 minutes to complete).  For my solution I used the TPL.  As each URL has no dependencies it was easy to simply encapsulate each in an object, place it into a collection, and pass that collection to a Parallel.ForEach() invocation.

As each download is completed we take a look at the page's contents, and depending upon what we find, we send that off for additional processing.

As I said this used to take the better part of a half an hour to complete, but it now runs in about 4.5 minutes (I have dual quad core Xeon processors @ 3GHz, Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit edition, and 24 GB of RAM .... plenty of power that is now being utilized, versus mostly wasting away).

I have been so impressed with Microsoft’s TPL that I have gone back to most of my legacy projects/code and refactored the designs to take advantage of TPL where possible, and I always give the “TPL treatment” on any new code I write (it’s not always possible if you have any type of dependency between loop iterations).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently using C# 5's new async features and WebClent instead of HttpWebRequest. You get some nice async methods with WebClient such as DownloadDataTaskAsync.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] data = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url)
```

Comment: That may be good to know, but it doesn't answer the question. Especially since the OP said he can't use `async`-`await`.